# Docker CPU and memory too low

Tags: docker

I am newbie to Docker world.  I could successfully build and run container with Tomcat.  But performance is very poor.  I logged into running system and found that only 2 cpu cores and 4 GB RAM is allocated.  Is it one of reason for bad performance, if so how can I allocate more resources.

I tried following command, but no luck..

```
docker run --rm -c 3 -p 32772:8080 --memory=8Gb -d helloworld
```

Any pointer will be helpful.

thanks in advance.

Comment: which OS? There is definitely something wrong, you should not need much memory or CPU

Comment: its based on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Docker for Windows/Mac? Then you can change it in the settings (Docker icon in the taskbar).
On Windows, Docker runs in Hyper-V without dynamic memory, so the memory will not be avalible to your system even if it isn't used.
With `docker info` you can find out how many resources are avalible.

The bad performace may also be caused by very slow file access on Docker for Mac.

On Linux, Docker has no upper limit by default.

The cpu and memory args of docker run limit the resources for one container, if they are not set there is no upper limit.